# Bytecode sequence decompilation

Tags: java, bytecode, decompiling

I have `byte[]` array which I know is a bytecode sequence for a method inside a class file.  Is there some way to perform selective decompilation of this `byte[]` array?  I do not have access to the actual `.class` file.
I have looked at Javassist library that has a lot of methods (`javassist.bytecode.CodeAttribute` class) but I was unable to find such specific methods.
Anyone have a clue?

I can take this `byte[]` array and produce the actual bytecode to JavaByte code mnemonics using the JVM reference manual but I need to produce the decompiled Java source code.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I've never heard of dealing with the bytecode for a single method. I think you're going to find that you can't do anything with it. What bytecode do you have? Where did you get it from? Are you familiar with the [class file format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html) and [how methods are stored](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.6)? For instance, the [name of a method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.6-200-A.9) is stored in [the constant pool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.4), which is part of the overall class file, not part of any one method. Keep reading about the method format to see what else has to be there. I very strongly suspect that either you don't have what you think you have in that `byte[]`, or else you're not going to have enough information to make anything of it.

Disclaimer: I've only dabbled in bytecode manipulation, so don't take what I say as authoritative. Believe what the spec says.

Comment: I got the bytecode from the JPDA method `com.sun.jdi.Method.bytecodes()` function call.  I want to decompile that so that I can just display the decompiled version of that function.  I understand that there might be issues (e.g., xrefs to protected, private, static variables, etc.).  But I was hoping there would be some way to decompile it.  I do have valid bytecode in my `byte[]` array because I wrote my own bytecode decompilation method which creates mnemonics from the obtained bytecode (I verified it with the output of `javap`).

Comment: Interesting. Well, there are decompilers out there. The only one I know for sure that offers a programmatic API is [Java Decompiler](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/). I guess it'll depend on how flexibile the decompiler is with regard to the input bytecode. I don't know JDI, but if you have a `com.sun.jdi.Method`, it seems you could make your way up to something representing the class and get more bytecode info. Perhaps something like `method.declaringType()`, which should give you a [ClassType](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jdk/api/jpda/jdi/com/sun/jdi/ClassType.html)?

Comment: Right, the `Method.declaringType()` only gives a `ReferenceType` object.  There is no method to get the bytecode from that object.  There is a `sourcePath()` and `sourceName()` function call though which may get me the filename of the source (assuming I have the source) but that may not be the case most of the time (which is why I need a decompiler in the first place).  I am not sure that JD-Eclipse guys offer a programmatic API.  I believe they have it for Eclipse.  Also, since it's closed source, I'd be reversing his / her released files which is not allowed per their license.

Answer (score 2):

It is impossible to produce valid Java source using only the bytecode of a specific method because all names are stored in the class wide constant pool, among other things. The best you can hope for is to generate bytecode mnemonics.